# Convert checksum to Delphi

Tags: delphi, checksum

I need to convert this code to Delphi, and I do not know how to:

```c
{
    LRC=0
    for (ch=1;ch<n+1;ch++){
        LRC=LRC^BYTE[ch];
    }
    LRC=LRC^ETX;
}
```

Comment: Which part of the task are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

The keys to understanding this are the following:

1. How to translate a C for loop into Delphi.
2. What the C operator `^` is. It is bitwise xor.

In Delphi the code would probably look like this:

```
function CalcChecksum(const buff: array of Byte): Byte;
const
  ETX = ...; // you'll need to obtain your value from the C source code
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for i := low(buff) to high(buff) do
    Result := Result xor buff[i];
  Result := Result xor ETX;
end;
```

The C code uses 1-based arrays which is, well, odd to say the least. In Delphi I would imagine an open array parameter would make most sense.

I rather imagine that the C code operates on an array of `unsigned char`, judging by the variable names. However, you really ought to make sure you understand the data types involved in case my guesswork is awry.